# how to get Nearby zipcode

Tags: wp-query, database, mysql

I need to get close/Nearby to zipcode list data zipcode so I'm using the example table name li_zipcode:

| id | zip_code | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 35004 | 33.557327 | -86.534508 |
| 2 | 35005 | 33.604744 | -87.042442 |
| 3 | 35006 | 33.429344 | -87.202103 |

My Code:

```
$zipcode = 35004;
              
$zipdetail = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `li_zipcode` WHERE `zip_code` = '$zipcode'", OBJECT );
    
    
 $latitude = $zipdetail->latitude;
    
  $longitude = $zipdetail->longitude;
    
  $radius = 40; //## this is 40 miles from given zipcode
    
   //## Now get list of zipcode nearby given zipcode
    
    
   $ziplist = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT zip_code, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($longitude) ) + sin( radians($latitude) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM li_zipcode HAVING distance < 25", OBJECT );
    
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($ziplist);
```

But its showing error as:

```
WordPress database error: [Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'radians']
SELECT zip_code, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians() ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians() ) + sin( radians() ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM li_zipcode HAVING distance < 25
```

It working fine if i run in phpmyadmin:

MySQL query: `SELECT zip_code, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(33.604744) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-87.042442) ) + sin( radians(33.604744) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM li_zipcode HAVING distance < 25`

Showing result:

| Zipcod | Distance |
| --- | --- |
| 35005 | 0 |
| 35006 | 15.214656078691721 |

please help me.

Comment: Doesn't `get_results()` return too much? Is `$latitude` even the value you expect? I think [`get_row()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/) might be a better fit for this.

Comment: @kero get_row() also showing same error

Comment: Can you print the query before running it? What does it show? If you use that query in e.g. PHPMyAdmin, will it work?

Comment: yes working with phpmyadmin but not working with WordPress

Comment: The exact same query? Can you add the final output of the query to the question? (Where variables are already resolved)

Comment: question updated with mysql query and result

Comment: The query is not correct. `radians( latitude )` should be `radians( 33.60477 )` instead (or whatever that number is).

Comment: See [this thread from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380645/incorrect-parameter-count-in-the-call-to-native-function-radians/34065533) for more info. Your variables are not interpolated correctly and most likely `NULL` or similar. So the query becomes `radians()` or `radians('')` which is not legal.

Comment: you were correct: this is solved : $zipdetail = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM `li_zipcode` WHERE `zip_code` = '$zipcode'", OBJECT );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your values `$latitude` and/or `$longitude` are not what you expect them to be. So `radians($latitdue)` becomes `radians()` or `radians('')`.

For getting a single row, [`get_row()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/) is usually the better choice instead of `get_results()`.

```
$zipdetail = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM `li_zipcode` WHERE `zip_code` = '$zipcode'", OBJECT );
```

If `$zipcode` is coming from an untrusted source (e.g. user input), make sure to [use a prepared statement](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference%2Fclasses%2Fwpdb%2Fprepare%2F/):

```
$zipdetail = $wpdb->get_row(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        'SELECT latitude, longitude FROM `li_zipcode` WHERE `zip_code` = %d',
        $zipcode
    ),
    OBJECT
);
```